# .NET Windows 7 Deployment: Error on adding event viewer entry

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-7-x64, event-viewer

My WPF application works fine on other machines. However when i deployed it on a 64-bit Win7 box it crashed when attempting to add an entry in the eventviewer. I could retrieve the following error details. Any ideas? Please help.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          10/21/2010 2:47:39 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      CB-PC
Description:
Faulting application name: AD.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4cbfcc08
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b727
Faulting process id: 0x600
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb7100c99f983c
Faulting application path: C:\Users\CB\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5VYKZRYR.PMG\PPMYKDWV.HJP\astr..tion_12ef0d73603d5a5a_0001.0000_0db54ee8dff50ae1\AstroDesktop.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0cac026a-dcf4-11df-8104-70f3958642a5
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-10-21T09:17:39.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1517</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>CB-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>AD.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>4cbfcc08</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data>
    <Data>4a5bdbdf</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0000b727</Data>
    <Data>600</Data>
    <Data>01cb7100c99f983c</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\CB\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5VYKZRYR.PMG\PPMYKDWV.HJP\astr..tion_12ef0d73603d5a5a_0001.0000_0db54ee8dff50ae1\AD.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>0cac026a-dcf4-11df-8104-70f3958642a5</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Does the event log source already exist?

Comment: No. Anyway could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need higher perms to create the event log than to add an event to it. Get your install app to create the event log instead of when you write "if the log doesn't exist, create it."